# azure change root directory linux web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I copied a website to the /wwwroot/public folder
now when I go to my azure webstie it just goes to the default screen of an azure website.

How can I change it so it goes to the/public folder. since I dont application settings and then virtual application and directories. option in azure

Answer (score -1):

You can add a redirect rule to redirect to /public folder using .htaccess in Apache or .conf file in Nginx.

Comment: I guess he/she does not want to REDIRECT, but change the root directory